# An example of switching expectation and infimum

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose $(X_t : t \geq 0)$ is a real valued stochastic process. In my case, it takes values in $[0,1]$, starts at $1$, and is decreasing. (It is also Markov).

I have calculated $\mathbb{E} (X_t) =: f(t)$ explicitly (i.e. I know what $f$ is; obviously, it is decreasing).

What I want to calculate is the expected time taken for $X_t$ to pass below a certain level, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(T)$ where

$$T:= \inf \{ t \geq 0 : X_t \leq a\} $$

for some fixed $a \in [0,1]$.

What I would like to be able to say is:

$$ \mathbb{E}(T)  =  \inf \{t \geq 0 : f(t) \leq a\} \quad ;$$

simply put, I have 'taken the expectation inside the infimum'.

I strongly suspect that this is not true, but I am wondering what sort of adaptations can be made in order to make the statement true...?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: If you have an expression for $P\left(X_{t}\leq a\right)$ then you
could use $\mathbb{E}T=\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left\{ T>t\right\} dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left\{ X_{t}>a\right\} dt$.

Comment: thanks, this is good, but unfortunately the distribution of $X_t$ is quite inaccessible. maybe instead of an equality, some sort of inequality holds in my question?